# CloudFirestorePlugin file not found

Tags: xcode, flutter

I had the problem below problem when running "flutter build iOS":

```
'cloud_firestore/CloudFirestorePlugin.h' file not found #import <cloud_firestore/CloudFirestorePlugin.h>`
```

App's work perfectly with my iPhone and the virtual iPhone

cocopod on lastest version

**xcode**: 11.2.1

**Package**: cloud_firestore: ^0.12.10+2 //last version

**podFile**

```
platform :ios, '13.1'

ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def parse_KV_file(file, separator='=')
  file_abs_path = File.expand_path(file)
  if !File.exists? file_abs_path
    return [];
  end
  pods_ary = []
  skip_line_start_symbols = ["#", "/"]
  File.foreach(file_abs_path) { |line|
      next if skip_line_start_symbols.any? { |symbol| line =~ /^\s*#{symbol}/ }
      plugin = line.split(pattern=separator)
      if plugin.length == 2
        podname = plugin[0].strip()
        path = plugin[1].strip()
        podpath = File.expand_path("#{path}", file_abs_path)
        pods_ary.push({:name => podname, :path => podpath});
      else
        puts "Invalid plugin specification: #{line}"
      end
  }
  return pods_ary
end

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!

  system('rm -rf .symlinks')
  system('mkdir -p .symlinks/plugins')

  generated_xcode_build_settings = parse_KV_file('./Flutter/Generated.xcconfig')
  if generated_xcode_build_settings.empty?
    puts "Generated.xcconfig must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first."
  end
  generated_xcode_build_settings.map { |p|
    if p[:name] == 'FLUTTER_FRAMEWORK_DIR'
      symlink = File.join('.symlinks', 'flutter')
      File.symlink(File.dirname(p[:path]), symlink)
      pod 'Flutter', :path => File.join(symlink, File.basename(p[:path]))
    end
  }

  plugin_pods = parse_KV_file('../.flutter-plugins')
  plugin_pods.map { |p|
    symlink = File.join('.symlinks', 'plugins', p[:name])
    File.symlink(p[:path], symlink)
    pod p[:name], :path => File.join(symlink, 'ios')
  }
end

install! 'cocoapods', :disable_input_output_paths => true

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'NO'
    end
  end
end
```

*PS. The comment lines were removed to make code shorter.*

Does anyone knows what is wrong with this task?

Answer (score 0):

i got this same error.

try the following which fixed it for me:

In Xcode, go to File > Workspace Settings, then select **"Legacy Build System"**

In my podfile - I have `platform :ios, '9.0'` Not sure if you need this but just fyi as I see your version is `13.1`

You might also need to run a `pod install` from the command line in the `<your_project_name/ios` directory if using VS Code (as VS Code did NOT correctly run/complete a pod install; VS Code version 1.40.2)

Just to note: I also found that the initial build -> launch on simulator, took a looooonnnggg time. I'm using a 2012 Macbook Pro which is big reason, but just fyi. it did eventually launch on the simulator and after that hot reload worked fine